# Recursively create subdirectories missing in second location

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to compare directory structures in a production server and a storage archive. I'm having trouble getting my python program to create folders in the archive that don't exist there but are on the production server.

I've found a few threads here that suggest using `report_full_closure()`, which actually yields what I need. There doesn't seem to be a way to parse the report, though, which would enable me to have python to automatically create the missing folders.

I've also attempted using `dircmp`, but it only gives me results for the immediate directories I pass to it, and not the subdirectories.

```
rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\archive'
archive = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\archive2'

dcmp = dircmp(rootdir, archive)

print 'Left :', dcmp.left_list
print 'Right :', dcmp.right_list

print 'Left Only:', dcmp.left_only
```

For instance, with a structure like below, it doesn't return that the folder test1 on the archive location doesn't have a folder called test5, or test5a. It will, however, return test3 in the 'Left Only' list.

root folder structure:

```
test1
   test5
      test5a
test2
test3
```

archive:

```
test1
test2
```